# How do I send an email to the initiator of a nintex workflow?

Tags: workflow

I need to create a nintex workflow:

1. I need to know who the workflow initiator is.
2. Put this information in a column in the item.
3. Use this information to send a message to the initiator.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workflow ‘Initiator’ value is automatically captured in the ‘Insert Reference’ Common metadata as shown below.

1. using a “Build dynamic string” action
2. insert reference: {Common:Initiator}
3. store the {Common:Initiator} metadata into a workflow variable
4. you can then use the variable to update a column in your List.
5. use var_Initiator workflow variable to update a column (field) in my List titled “Initiator”.

Comment: Hi Liron, do you know Liron?

Comment: You only have to go through that if the field you want to update is not a person/group field.

Answer (score 2):

Nintex provides a method to see who started the workflow, it is defined as the Initiator in the Common workflow variables.  So when your workflow is triggered, you'd update a list item and set the column to the Initiator.  Then you'd send a notification and select the Initiator as the To person.